# If two columns match paste them together, otherwise do nothing

Tags: r

I have a `DF1`

```
SNP a
rs1 1  
rs2 2  
rs3 3 
rs4 4
```

And `DF2`

```
SNP  GENE
rs1   A
rs2   B
```

I am looking for the way to get `DF3`

```
SNP    a
rs1_A  1
rs2_B  2
rs3    3
rs4    4
```

I have tried to use `ifelse` statement such as

```
ifelse(DF1$SNP %in% DF2$SNP,paste(DF1$SNP, DF2$GENE,sep="_"),DF1$SNP)
```

But it didnt work.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to replace the `%in%` with `,` in `paste`

```
DF1$SNP <- ifelse(DF1$SNP %in% DF2$SNP,paste(DF1$SNP, DF2$GENE,sep="_"),DF1$SNP)
DF1$SNP
#[1] "rs1_A" "rs2_B" "rs3"   "rs4"
```

If we are creating a new objects

```
DF3 <- transform(DF1, SNP = ifelse(SNP %in% DF2$SNP, paste(SNP, DF2$GENE, sep="_"), SNP))
```

NOTE: Here, we assume the columns are `character` class and not `factor`

Comment: sorry typo error. but it still seems to be not working

Comment: @ThePooh  What is the error?  I get the expected output.  If you have a `factor` column, convert to `character` will `as.character` and then it should work

Comment: Right, one of the columns was factor. Thank you!